# Error :Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;    
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class webdriver {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.navigate().to("http://www.calculator.net");
    }
}
```

Firefox : 47.0
Selenium WebDriver: 2.53.1

Please guide how to proceed.

Comment: Unable to open website because of below error Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'My', ip: '10.0.12.150', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Comment: Have you tried to downgrade FF to 46?

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below points help you.:

1. Browser instances are not closed properly. Make sure you close the browser sessions.
2. Firefox browser and Webdriver version being incompatible.
3. You are running out of ports. Try increasing the limit as per the resolution in Microsoft KB article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/196271 and restart your machine